# PHPMailer XAMPP SMTP Authentication failed

Tags: php, xampp, gmail, phpmailer

I'm trying to use PHPMailer to send e-mail from my local virtual host on XAMPP with the code below. I have enabled extension=php_openssl.dll in php.ini, still I get the error messages below. Anyone knows why?

```
require_once 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require_once 'class.phpmailer.php';
require_once 'class.smtp.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->Username = "xxx";
$mail->Password = "xxx";

$email = "xxx@gmail.com";
$name = "Test";
$email_from = "xxx@gmail.com";
$name_from = "Test";

$mail->AddAddress($email, $name);
$mail->SetFrom($email_from, $name_from);
$mail->Subject = "My Subject";
$mail->Body = "Mail contents";

try{
    $mail->Send();
    echo "Success!";
} catch(Exception $e){
    echo "Fail - " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Error output:
SMTP ERROR: Password command failed: 534-5.7.14
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.

Comment: You are using an old version of PHPMailer and have based your code on an old example. You've specified `SMTPDebug = 2`, but you have not provided the output it generates.

Comment: It's very likely you're running into a gmail problem that's very well documented, so [read the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) that tells you how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

For those having issues with failing authentication using PHPMailer, and all settings and credentials are good, try using this:

```
$mail->AuthType = 'LOGIN';
```

in the PHP that is attempting to send the email.

I struggled for the longest, until I added this.

Cheers.